# Background in the 3D view appears black instead of transparent

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, transparency

When in the rendered shading view the background is normally transparent, but all of a sudden it turned black. I don't know if I accidentally pushed a button, and I don't know how to turn in back to transparent.

The *Transparent Film* option is checked in the render properties panel.
What did I miss?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Odd.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend which demonstrates this?

Comment: @gandalf3 how do I upoad a blendfile?

Comment: Upload it to some hosting service (e.g. [pasteall](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/system_keyboard_svg.py) or [blendexchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)) and put the link here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to have a background image which is being displayed under the viewport render. If you disable it in *3D view > Properties region* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Background Images*, the transparent background is visible once more:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens while looking at the Render Result, check your channels of the image to draw.

[image: Screenshot of Chanel Buttons - RGB activated]

[image: Screenshot of Chanel Buttons - RGBA activated]

Comment: the question was about the 3D view, not looking at the render result.